# Default value when property is missing with project() step in Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

I have following graph:

```
g.addV('TEST').property(id, 't1')
g.addV('TEST').property(id, 't2').property('a', 1)
```

If I do:
`g.V('t2').project('a').by(values('a'))` the traversal works and returns map with key `a` because property is there.

But if I have project step in my traversal like following:
`g.V('t1').project('a').by(values('a'))`

Because `a` is missing it returns error, is there any way to return null or empty value in such case from `by()` step to avoid this error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().project('a').by(coalesce(values('a'),constant('default')))
==>[a:default]
==>[a:1]
```

Comment: Ah, yes `constant()` was what I was looking for, but couldn't find. Thank you for answering so quickly!