# How to set default values or return null value for a property which is missing in the graph and is been queried in the project() step

Tags: gremlin

Referring to this previously asked question:
[Default value when property is missing with project() step in Gremlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669894/default-value-when-property-is-missing-with-project-step-in-gremlin)
Is there a more efficient way to do the same thing or preferably returning "null" in the latest gremlin version as each coalesce step takes 2 additional traversals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gremlin will not have a notion of a `null` traverser [until 3.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57460156/1831717) is released (there is no schedule for release at this time). Here are some of examples of what to expect from 3.5.0:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name','allen')
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','allen').project('name','age').by('name').by('age')
==>[name:allen,age:null]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','allen').elementMap()
==>[id:0,label:person,name:allen]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','allen').elementMap('name','age')
==>[id:0,label:person,name:allen]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','allen').values('name','age')
==>allen
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','allen').union(values('name'),values('age'))
==>allen
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','allen').union(values('name'),coalesce(values('age'),constant(null)))
==>allen
==>null
```

There shouldn't be much loss in efficiency for using `coalesce()` even if you must use many of them. The cost of `constant()` is not an issue and `values(String)` assuming that's all you're doing will compile to a fast `TokenTraversal`. I suppose the big loss is having to type a lot. I'm not aware of any graph databases (maybe [sqlg](https://github.com/pietermartin/sqlg) since it's based on relational backends?) that support default values as most don't have notion of a schema.